# Key Pressing partially working

Tags: java, c++, keypress

I've been trying to do some kind of autoclicker and have the following code in java:

```
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.*;

class keyStroke {
    public void Execute() throws AWTException {
        int n = 0;
        while(n < 100){
            Robot r = new Robot();
            r.delay(1000);
            r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_1);
            r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_1);
            ++n;
        }
    }
}
```

It works pretty fine clicking the key 1, but, it doesn't work in some games.

It looks to be working only on chatbox and accessing to it (enter key), but aside from that, nothing else works (like using a skill or moving).

Then, I decided to also try in C++, with the following code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

void SendKey (char Vk){
    char VkKey = VkKeyScan(Vk);
    keybd_event(VkKey, 0, 0, 0); 
    keybd_event(VkKey, 0, KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0);
}

int main(){
    while(true){
        SendKey('1');
        Sleep(1000);
    }
}
```

And the same thing happens.

What am U doing wrong? If the keypress doesn't work for this case I have to find something else?

Comment: maybe those games do not use the standard keyevents but another way to get keyboard input?

Comment: Agree with @stijn. Also what if you place a small delay between key press and release. OTOH, for something completely unique, you could always play the game honestly.

Comment: FYI, you are creating 100 instances of Robot class in the Java version.

Answer (score 0):

I know from experience that some game input doesn't use an event based structure. Some games only check once every frame if a key is pressed. This means that your chance of pressing the key at that exact moment are zero.

Scripting utilities such as the logitech keyboard scripting tool face a similar problem and there it helps to have a delay between press and release.

Aside: chat windows usually have to use an input event as typing would be almost impossible if key presses are only registered once per frame.